# Throwing Custom Exceptions From Post Install Script

Tags: managed-package, exception, postinstall

We have created a post-installation script for a Managed Package.

As we are using lightning components in my package, the domain must be enabled.

In post-installation script, we are checking whether the domain is enabled.

If not enabled, we would like to throw an exception to the end user saying that 'Domain isn't enabled. Please contact System Administrator'.

Please help us resolve

Comment: Can you elaborate "throw an exception to the end user"? How do imagine that in salesforce UI terms? Would not that be wiser to mention that in prerequisites?

Comment: I would like to let know the installing user that, this package cannot be installed, as they've not enabled domain in their org. Instead of showing 'The post install script failed' error, I would like to show some detailed error message.